# Swift: Dynamically change cell height depending on number of cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` grid system where `indexPath.item % 3 == 0 ? largeCellSize : smallCellSize` and it works. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M11kE.jpg) is a screenshot of what it looks like. The `UICollectionView` is inside a cell of a `UITableViewCell` and that `UITableView` is inside a `ViewController`.

The `UITableViewCell` height is determined by how many cells are in the `UICollectionView`. So the cell height should increase when there's a `largeCellSize` is available because the `smallCellSize` follow after the `largeCellSize`.

For example: Large, small, small -> *increase cell height* -> large, small, small -> *increase cell height* -> and etc... and there's really no multiple because it's the large cells occurs in the 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th, 13th, 16th, etc...

The size of the `largeCellSize` is `400` and the `smallCellSize` is `200`. So basically, the `UITableViewCell` size should only increase by `400` when the there's this *1st, 4th, 7th, 10th, 13th, 16th, etc...* "pattern" number of cells.

How can I approach this by making sure the cell height increases by `400` when appropriate?

CODE:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: // Ignore this...
        return 110
    case 1: // Problem is here...
        let productCellCount = self.productsArray.count

        print("---------- heighForRowAt")
        print(productCellCount)

        // I can't seem to get the right logic to show just until the last cell.
        // This shows the last cell and then a bunch of empty space.
        // As for the false, it shows 6 out of the 11 cell and
        // the large cell that it's supposed to show it shows only half of it

        return CGFloat(productCellCount % 3 == 0 ? Double(400 * productCellCount / 2) : 200 * ceil(Double(productCellCount / 2)))
    default:
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Just to clarify, I have two cells in my `UITableView`, the second holding the `UICollectionView` that is being populated with data from Firebase. As the data increases/decreases the number of cells obviously will change. Depending on the number of cells the height of the `UITableViewCell` will increase/decrease.

Comment: Hi there- I’m not quite sure what the problem is. You’ve said you’ve been able to implement the layout for a large cell size of 400 and small cell size of 200. Do you want these values to change as the number of rows in the table changes and then update the UI?

Comment: @Sparky Basically the table view cell size should increase and update the ui so the use can see new content and not like show half of the larger cell. The way I’ve done it it won’t updates when the number of cells is divisible by 4 but that shows half a cell at certain number of cells.

Comment: OK, got you. Could you post some code? Are you using a subclassed layout manager or doing it via delegation for a standard layout manager? If the latter, have you implemented sizeForItemAt?

Comment: @Sparky Updated the question with the code! The problem is in dealing with the table view cell size to show according to how much cells there are and to increase the tableview cell size as the pattern 1, 4, 7,10, 13, n+3 cells increase...

Comment: instead of your current approach, maybe this is what you are looking for: `switch (indexPath.row % 3 == 0) { case true: return 400.0; default: return UITableViewAutomaticDimension }`, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I think the following should do what you are looking for:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: // Ignore this...
        return 110
    case 1: // Problem is here...

        let productCellCount : Int = self.productsArray.count
        let remainder : Int = productCellCount % 3
        let numberOfTriads : Int = (productCellCount - remainder) / 3

        print(#function)
        print("PRODUCT CELL COUNT: \(productCellCount) NUMBER OF TRIADS: \(numberOfTriads) REMAINDER: \(remainder)")
        print("REQUIRED HEIGHT: \(((numberOfTriads) * 400) + (remainder > 0 ? 400 : 0))")    
        // New code

        return CGFloat(((numberOfTriads) * 400) + (remainder > 0 ? 400 : 0))

    default:
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}
```

Obviously this works only if you are sure that every third row needs the height specified. A more robust implementation would perhaps query the collection view to be placed within each cell and return the height it requires.

Hope that helps.

Comment: No, sorry you have it confused. There are only two table view cells. The first is not important and the second contains a uicollectionview. Data is being populated into the uicollectionview and the second table view cell's height is determined by how many cells the inner uicollectionview contains. so if it's 1-3 cells inside the uicollectionview then the table view cell height should 400, if it's 4-6 then 800, 7-9 then 1200, so on and so forth.

Comment: @MohamedMohamed please see edit. (That's the trouble with trying to dash an answer off quickly in your lunch break!)

Answer (score 1):

Implement `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` [UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview) method. Put in there the condition you need regarding your `indexPath` logic and every time you reload the table it should render correctly

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your comments :- "if it's 1-3 cells inside the uicollectionview then the table view cell height should 400, if it's 4-6 then 800, 7-9 then 1200, so on and so forth"

So now what you can do is in your tableview cellForRowAt method you can check how many items are there in your UICollectionView and then set particular height to some variable and reload the tableView. Later in heightForRowAt set that variable height to particular indexPath.row cell.